# How to solve .xib file conflicts in Git

Tags: iphone, git, xib, conflict

I am using git repository for a iphone project. When i pulled from git after committing my work i got conflict in one of my .xib file and auto merging is done sucessfully. But after the auto merging process that .xib file is destroyed. This happens to me two or three times.  can anyone give me a proper solution for this issue?

Comment: what do you mean by destroyed ? is it the entire xib file or just your modification that is gone ? did you find what produces this conflict ?

Comment: destroyed means when i opened that file in the interface builder its shows "Could not read the archive"

Comment: what happens if you checkout instead of pull ?

Answer (score 0):

Nib files are stored in an XML Format which can usually be handled by git. I wouldn't do an auto-merge on XML files though, because the structure can be corrupted which probably happened in your case. If you open a nib file in a text-editor, you'll be able to guess how the nib file is built. I would then try to do a manual merge, keeping the object structure in the nib file intact.

Comment: How we can avoid auto merging in .xib file?